# store data in 10 db at one query

Tags: php, pdo

It is good idea to save data on 10 database servers and more using one query?? Something like saving cluster data.

Example:

```
$cluster = array(

 'pdo1' => new PDO('host_1','dbname1','dbuser1','dbpass1');

 'pdo2' => new PDO('host_2','dbname1','dbuser1','dbpass1');

 'pdo3' => new PDO('host_3','dbname1','dbuser1','dbpass1');

 'pdo4' => new PDO('host_4','dbname1','dbuser1','dbpass1');


);

$i=0;

foreach($cluser as $ket => $value){

    $done = $value->execute('myquery);

    if($done){

    $i++;
    }

}

if($i == count($cluster)){
   echo ('yeah i store data in 4 databases at one run');

}
```

Im dont have muc experience with using clusters db and really dont know how these work. Can some one help understand?

Comment: No, this is a bad idea. Look into replication.

Comment: agreed with @DannyBeckett, also you have a syntax error  
$done = $value->execute('myquery);

Comment: It wouldn't be much a cluster if you need to write to them individually...

Comment: why it isn`t? performace shuting down?? How biggest webs store data in multi databases?? Hmmm datas first go into one database and than other script make backup in antohers database servers?

Comment: Danny what you a mean look into replication?? I would understand how working biggest webs. About my syntax error i just want show you my idea i write this very faster and i made mistakes.

Comment: he means.. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html (but every other database should work basicly the same)

Comment: so, that mean multi saving to multi databases is maded in database server (when is configure to do that) not in server (apache2) where program has runing?? So if i want cluster saving data i have to configure my database server right? not my php code??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it's not the developer's job to insert into multiple DB (in that particular case, which is a replication context).
In the DB universe, there's a replication mode doing that for you.

You insert in a "master" db, and then that one, on its own, will copy the diff it has to all its slaves, (a)synchronously.

In bigger websites, you might not even know the infrastructure of the data layer, imagine some openstack or aws app with heavy traffic, adding db instances on the fly. You, as developer, don't have to know the infrastructure, or each time an instance is created, you'd have to add it to your cluster config, and you just can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

ugly coding.

saving data on 10 database servers and more using one query is necessary.

however, it's not ok to implement the replication by developer.

And mysql, redis and other storage has the replication mechanism， which has better expansibility and performance.

Learn more about the mysql replication from the official site.http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication.html